# how recover password by smtp error 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, smtp

- I'm trying to register new user with confirmation email using `smtp` under controller 
  knowing that is working normal before and recover password by email too.

Question is  `how recover password by smtp` thanks.

. This is my **`web.config`** file :

```
      <appSettings>
        <!--Smptp Server (confirmations emails)-->
        <add key="toEmail" value="haniyac1@gmail.com" />
        <add key="Password" value="password" />
        <add key="Port" value="587" />
        <add key="Host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <add key="enableSsl" value="true"/>
        <add key="defaultCredentials" value="false"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp from="haniyac1@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="haniyac1" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" password="password" port="587"/>
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>


  <system.net>
```

- This is `IdentityConfig.cs` file :

> ```
>   public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
>     {
>
>
>         public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
>         {
>             SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
>             client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
>             client.EnableSsl=true;
>             return client.SendMailAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toEmail"],
>                                         message.Destination,
>                                         message.Subject,
>                                         message.Body);
>         }
>     }
> ```

and finaly this is my actionResult Register in `Account controller` :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // Pour plus d'informations sur l'activation de la confirmation de compte et de la réinitialisation de mot de passe, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Envoyer un message électronique avec ce lien
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrll = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, Code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmez votre compte", "Confirmez votre compte en cliquant <a href=\"" + callbackUrll + "\">ici</a>");

                //string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");

                //await this.UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, model.Roles);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles.Where(a => !a.Name.Contains("Admins")), "Name", "Name");
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // Si nous sommes arrivés là, un échec s’est produit. Réafficher le formulaire
        return View(model);
    }




                                                                              cordially
```

Comment: Please add your actual specific question.

Comment: I want to retrieve password by gmail . thanks